# How to call correct this in Angular Service in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, this, angular-services

I have a TypeScript angular project and want to refactor it to use services. My problem is now that I call this in the service but at runtime it is not the service class as expected but the controller class. How can I call functions inside my service from the service itself?

Here are the relevant code fragments:

Helper Service

```
export interface IHelperService {
    Log(msg: string): void;
    GetModel(model: string): Array<any>;
}

export class HelperService implements IHelperService {
    public GetModel(model: string): Array<any> {
        return this.getModelEnum(model);
    }

    private getModelEnum(model: string): Array<any> {
        ...
    }
}

let module: angular.IModule = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTouch"]);
module.service('HelperSvc', HelperService);
```

Controller

```
constructor($scope: angular.IScope, $http: angular.IHttpService, helperSvc: IHelperService) {
    this.Scope.GetModel = helperSvc.GetModel;
}
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="ae.Scope.Model"
    ng-options="type.Id as type.Value for type in GetModel('Types')"></select>
```

Results in

**`Error: this.getModelEnum is not a function`**

This worked fine as long as the GetModel/getModelEnum functions were inside the controller.

*(What bothered me most was that google always stripped `this` from my search query. Results were about something completely different then of course...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both TypeScript and JavaScript the `this` reference inside a function is determined on the call site. Calling `controller.Scope.GetModel()` will bind the `this` reference to the scope object instead of the helper service.

All you have to do is to is to explicitly bind `this`:

```
this.Scope.GetModel = helperSvc.GetModel.bind(helperSvc);
// or
this.Scope.GetModel = (model:string): Array<any> => helperSvc.GetModel(model);
```

Or use the function bind syntax if you have a compiler that supports it:

```
this.Scope.GetModel = ::helperSvc.GetModel;
```

Comment: Since `helperSvc.GetModel` isn't just some callback or event handler but a regular method, an arrow wrapper seems to be more applicable to the situation.

Comment: perfect, the arrow wrapper was exactly what I was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are setting on scope a direct reference to the **GetModel** method thus losing the context of the **helperSvc** when it is later called.

You should always call the service via a service object.

```
this.Scope.helper = helperSvc;
```

And in HTML.

```
<select ng-model="ae.Scope.Model"
ng-options="type.Id as type.Value for type in helper.GetModel('Types')"></select>
```